# Join sub tables to main table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three declared tables:

- Table_1 (default) has group number in common with that both sub Table_2 and Table_3
- while Table_2 and Table_3 have dates in common

**I am having difficulty in joining both sub tables to T1 without losing data after the first join. Instead of `NULL`, T1 should still have its inital data after T2 is joined.**

I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT * from @GRP_TABLE as T1
        FULL OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT * FROM @PASSEDBOOKINGS) AS T2
        on T1.T1_GROUP_NUMBER = T2.T2_GROUP_NUMBER  
       FULL OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT * FROM @FAILBOOKINGS)AS T3
        ON T3.T3_GROUP_NUMBER = T1.T1_GROUP_NUMBER
         and T3.T3_DATE = T2.T2_DATE
    )AS JOINS

WHERE JOINS.T3_DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
OR JOINS.T2_DATE =  CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

@GRP_TABLE AS T1:

```
|-------|------------------|
|T1_LINE| T1_GROUP_NUMBER  | 
|-------|------------------|
|  A1   |        A110      |
|-------|------------------|
|  A1   | A120             |
|-------|------------------|
|A1     |A130              |
|-------|------------------|
|A1     |A140              |
|-------|------------------|
|A1     |A150              |
|-------|------------------|
```

@PASSEDBOOKING AS T2:

```
|---------------|-----------|----------|
|T2_GROUP_NUMBER| T2_COUNTS | T2_DATE  |
|---------------|-----------|----------|
|  A110         | 2         |2019-02-25|
|---------------|-----------|----------|
|  A120         | 2         |2019-02-25|
|---------------|-----------|----------|
|A130           |2          |2019-02-25|
|---------------|-----------|----------|
```

@FAILEDBOOKINGS AS T3:

```
|---------------|-----------|----------|
|T3_GROUP_NUMBER| T3_COUNTS | T3_DATE  |
|---------------|-----------|----------|
|  A140         | 1         |2019-02-25|
|---------------|-----------|----------|
|  A150         | 1         |2019-02-25|
|---------------|-----------|----------|
```

This results in:

```
|-------|------------------|------------------|----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------|------------------|
|T1_LINE| T1_GROUP_NUMBER  | T2_GROUP_NUMBER  |T2_COUNTS | T3_GROUP_NUMBER |T3_COUNTS    |      T2_DATE     | T3_DATE          |
|-------|------------------|------------------|----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------|------------------|
|  NULL |        NULL      |        NULL      |     NULL |  A140           |       1     |      NULL        |   2019-02-25     |
|-------|------------------|------------------|----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------|------------------|
|  NULL | NULL             |          NULL    | NULL     |A150             |        1    |      NULL        |   2019-02-25     |
|-------|------------------|------------------|----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------|------------------|
|A1     |A110              |    A110          |     2    |      NULL       |    NULL     |      2019-02-25  |   NULL           |
|-------|------------------|------------------|----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------|------------------|
|A1     |A120              |    A120          |     2    |      NULL       |    NULL     |      2019-02-25  |   NULL           |
|-------|------------------|------------------|----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------|------------------|
|A1     |A130              |    A130          |     2    |      NULL       |    NULL     |      2019-02-25  |       NULL       |
|-------|------------------|------------------|----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------|------------------|
```

But I am expecting these results:

```
|-------|------------------|------------------|----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------|------------------|
|T1_LINE| T1_GROUP_NUMBER  | T2_GROUP_NUMBER  |T2_COUNTS | T3_GROUP_NUMBER |T3_COUNTS    |      T2_DATE     | T3_DATE          |
|-------|------------------|------------------|----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------|------------------|
|  A1   |        A140      |        NULL      |     NULL |  A140           |       1     |      NULL        |   2019-02-25     |
|-------|------------------|------------------|----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------|------------------|
|  A1   | A150             |          NULL    | NULL     |A150             |        1    |      NULL        |   2019-02-25     |
|-------|------------------|------------------|----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------|------------------|
|A1     |A110              |    A110          |     2    |      NULL       |    NULL     |      2019-02-25  |   NULL           |
|-------|------------------|------------------|----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------|------------------|
|A1     |A120              |    A120          |     2    |      NULL       |    NULL     |      2019-02-25  |   NULL           |
|-------|------------------|------------------|----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------|------------------|
|A1     |A130              |    A130          |     2    |      NULL       |    NULL     |      2019-02-25  |       NULL       |
|-------|------------------|------------------|----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data please? The results you got are helpful, but they don't show us what your data looked like *before* your query, only after. Make sure that the sample data is representative of the data you've supplied above. Thanks.

Comment: @Larnu thanks, see update.

Comment: I see that all your sql is with `@-`tables: maybe you can put your example on [a rexter wall](https://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler) ?

Comment: Blocked by company unfortunately :( @AlexYu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using COALESCE function - so if the data is not present in one table pick it up from another

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the null output

1. Even if T1 table contains A140 and A150 then the corresponding T2 and T3 dates are not the same actually the dates does not exist from your sample data.

To get the expected out put as you mention you can do the following,

```
SELECT *
From
 @GRP_TABLE as T1
Left JOIN
 @PASSEDBOOKINGS AS T2
on T1.T1_GROUP_NUMBER = T2.T2_GROUP_NUMBER  
Left JOIN
@FAILBOOKINGS AS T3
        ON T3.T3_GROUP_NUMBER = T1.T1_GROUP_NUMBER
WHERE T3.T3_DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
OR T2.T2_DATE =  CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking to your data seems you need  left  join

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.T1_LINE, T1.T1_GROUP_NUMBER
    ,  T2.T2_GROUP_NUMBER , T2.T2_COUNT
    , T3.T3_GROUP_NUMBER, T2.T2_COUNTS,  T2.T2_DATE, T3.T3_DATE, T3.T3_COUNT 
from @GRP_TABLE T1 
LEFT JOIN @PASSEDBOOKING T2 ON T1.T1_GROUP_NUMBER = T2.T2_GROUP_NUMBER 
LEFT JOIN @FAILEDBOOKINGS AS T3  ON T1.T1_GROUP_NUMBER = T3.T2_GROUP_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 1):

FULL OUTER JOIN is very expensive, and I don't see a reason to use it here. You have a primary table in which you always want data returned, and two secondary tables - so a classic case of FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2, T3...

Consider this instead.

```
    SELECT *
FROM @GRP_TABLE as T1
LEFT JOIN @PASSEDBOOKINGS AS T2
        on T1.T1_GROUP_NUMBER = T2.T2_GROUP_NUMBER  
        and T2.T2_DATE =  CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
LEFT JOIN  @FAILBOOKINGS AS T3
        ON T3.T3_GROUP_NUMBER = T1.T1_GROUP_NUMBER
         and T3.T3_DATE = T2.T2_DATE
```

I'm not even sure you have to join date to date, given that both tables are limited to one date anyway.:

```
SELECT *
FROM @GRP_TABLE as T1
LEFT JOIN @PASSEDBOOKINGS AS T2
        on T1.T1_GROUP_NUMBER = T2.T2_GROUP_NUMBER  
        and T2.T2_DATE =  CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
LEFT JOIN  @FAILBOOKINGS AS T3
        ON T3.T3_GROUP_NUMBER = T1.T1_GROUP_NUMBER
         and T3.T3_DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Also consider unioning T2 and T3, might make more sense!

```
SELECT *
FROM @GRP_TABLE as T1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'pass' as type, * FROM @PASSEDBOOKINGS WHERE DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE
                UNION
            SELECT 'fail' as type, * FROM @FAILBOOKINGS WHERE DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE
            ) 
            T2 on T2.GROUP_NUMBER = T1.GROUP_NUMBER
```

Comment: Thanks, the date condition was only added to limit data, there are data from 3 weeks back, which is why am joining on dates.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` only returns the first binded table i.e T2 data

Comment: T2 and T3 are both gonna return rows so long as the groupnumber is on t1. In this case you're limiting T3 to dates that are on T2 though - is that intentional design?

Comment: Yes, they are used elsewhere in the script. Someone suggested `Coalesce`, that gives similar result as am expecting, so am going to use that. Thanks :)